# Error when trying to add positionLine on chart

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I'm facing very weird issue when trying to add position line to my tradingview chart.

Here's the code:

```
const positionLine = chart.createPositionLine();

positionLine.setPrice(Number(price));
positionLine.setQuantity();
positionLine.setLineColor("#f2c200");
positionLine.setText("");
```

When I try to run this, I receive following error:

[image]

If I remove code after `createPositionLine()`, the error still occurs.

I also tried passing options parameter to `createPositionLine()`, but that didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

I am using latest build of charting library.

Comment: setQuantity probably requires a value, as every position will have some open size.

Comment: But it crashes before I even get to run setQuantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone running into the same issue, I found a solution!

It turns out, the error was caused by chart not being fully initialized. Executing my code with some timeout fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try once Chart is ready, no need to set timeout

widget.onChartReady(function () {

```
        var chart = widget.chart();

        chart.setVisibleRange({
            from: Date.UTC(2018, 7, 1) / 1000,
            to: Date.UTC(2020, 1, 1) / 1000
        });

        highPosition = chart.createPositionLine()
            .setText(highPoint.title+":" + highPoint.price)
            .setQuantity(highPoint.volume)
            .setLineLength(3)
        //.colors.lineColor('red')
        highPosition.setPrice(highPoint.price);


        lowPosition = chart.createOrderLine()
            .setText(lowPoint.title + ":" + lowPoint.price )
            .setLineLength(3)
            .setQuantity(lowPoint.volume);
        lowPosition.setPrice(lowPoint.price);

        
    
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).